# Debian Linux PATH variable repeats path

Tags: linux, debian, path

I have Debian Gnu/Linux 11.3.0 64 bit. In `/etc/profile` file I have defined my PATH variable as such:

```
PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:$HOME/.local/bin"
```

When I,

```
echo $PATH
```

it yields,

**`/home/db/.local/bin`**`:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:`**`/home/db/.local/bin`**

The path, `/home/db/.local/bin`, is repeated. If I take out `$HOME/.local/bin` from the PATH variable, it expectedly yields:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

This is not a problem for me, just curious as to why the `$HOME/.local/bin` repeats in the PATH echo? It only does it for `$HOME/.local/bin`. If I put something like `/usr/loca/sbin`, `/usr/sbin`, `/opt`, it doesn't do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a local `~/.profile` file that also appends the `$HOME/.local/bin` piece to the `PATH` environment variable, in addition to the global `/etc/profile`. On my Debian machine for example, there is this bit in my `~/.profile`:

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

When searching `PATH`, the first match is used. So it would make sense that `~/.profile` would want to ensure the user's private bin is first in line. Otherwise, if the user had custom versions of binaries that exist in `/usr/local/bin` or `/usr/bin`, the custom version would not be used.